# add value to column after select

Tags: sql

I have a button the executes a `SELECT` statement. When that button is clicked I need a query that counts + 1 in the column `records`.

So `records` can be 2. When I click the button + 1 should be added, so the new number in the column is 3. I am not quite sure how to do that. Is it modify column I have to use here?

```
ALTER stores MODIFY COLUMN records INT COUNT + 1;
```

Comment: You might want to look into creating a stored procedure.  Sounds like you are very new to SQL and programming.

Comment: A stored procedure for just incrementing a value in a column is overkill, IMO, and much more complicated. But yes, some basic SQL tutorial is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Stored procedures are best practice for manipulating data in relational databases.  Everyone who wants to "IncrementCount" does it via the `IncrementCount` procedure.  Besides throwing shade at an industry best practice, do you have a suggestion for the OP?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided the columns in your table and the primary key you will be selecting from. So how do you distinguish which row in the stores (table?) will get the column records incremented?

Answer (score -1):

First you have to stock the int you get in your first select query, I dont know which language you use but something like that

```
int result = "SELECT records FROM stores"
```

Then you increment your result

```
result++;
```

And you update the column with the new value

```
UPDATE stores SET records = " + result
```